# Stemming library/plugin for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tagging, stemming

Looking for a [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) library in Ruby which will allow me to create such mappings as:

```
maps_to["dogs"] = "dog"
maps_to["puppies"] = "dog"
maps_to["doggies"] = "dog"
etc
```

Comment: This is actually [lemmatisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : https://rubygems.org/gems/stemmer4r/

Stemming may not work the way most people think stemming works though.